# I'm creating a dll and looking for current SHA-3 C# code

Tags: c#, hash

Need Current SHA-3 C# code?

Greetings,

Does anybody know of good SHA-3 C# code? I'm trying to create my own little dll file in C#. So I'm not really looking for libraries like Bouncy Castle.

I've been running into numerous code examples that say they are SHA-3, but in fact are actually SHA-3 (Keccak) using old code. It's my understanding that although Keccak was the winner, there his been a slight padding change of one bit and the name officially became SHA-3. see FIPS 202.

So I'm looking for SHA3–256 coding that produces an empty string hash of "a7ffc6f8bf1ed76651c14756a061d662f580ff4de43b49fa82d80a4b80f8434a". The older version (Keccak-256) produces "c5d2460186f7233c927e7db2dcc703c0e500b653ca82273b7bfad8045d85a470" from an empty string.

Another option would be adding the padding change to the current implementation. However, that's something I don't know how to do.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

My original SHA3 port is available:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/SHA3/1.0.0-rc
https://github.com/jdluzen/sha3/tree/netstandard

Use the property `UseKeccakPadding` to control which padding you need.

This is a self contained port on top of `System.Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithm`. It's very small, and can be used directly as is.

Comment: Thank you Joe for responding. Originally I had looked at that web site. However, when I went to the project site I noticed that there hasn't been any updates since 2012. This makes it unlikely that it is the updated 2015 SHA3. So the SHA3 -Version 1.0.0-rc package may be up to date but the source code isn't. Do you have any idea where the updated source code is hanging out? I wasn't looking to install an additional dll. Just much rather utilize the classes.

Thanks again for your response.

Comment: Yes, the updated code is on the netstandard branch. I need to clean it up and merge it in soon.